# C: Program to delete characters other than alphabetical

Tags: c, arrays, string, ctype

so I'm trying to create a program which looks at a string defined in main, and deletes any non-alphabetical characters (excluding \0). So far this is my code:

```
/* Write code to which considers the string currently saved
 * in the 'name' array, removes all spaces and non-alphabetical
 * chars from the string, and makes all alphabetical characters
 * lower case. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMELEN 30

int main (void) {
  char name[NAMELEN];
  strcpy(name, " William B. Gates");
    int i, length, check;

    length = strlen(name);
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        check = isalpha(name[i]);
        if ( check == 0 ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                name[i] = name[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The length is %lu.\n", strlen(name));

  printf("Name after compression: %s\n", name);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So for the test data, " William B. Gates", the output should be "WilliamBGates", unfortunately the output I'm getting is:

```
The length is 16.
Name after compression: William B. Gates
```

I think the space before William has been deleted, but I'm unable to tell.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: @user3121023 changed it to `length = strlen(name);
 for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
  check = isalpha(name[i]);
  if ( check == 0 ) {
   for ( j = i ; j < length; j++ ) {
    name[j] = name[j+1];
   }
  }
 }` getting output `WilliamB Gates` why isn't it deleting the second space?

Comment: You don't need double loops for this at all. You need a source and destination  pointer, and a single traversal through the string.

Comment: @WhozCraig how would I even go about doing that. I'm avery basic programmer and I'm only doing these questions for exam practice, not out of want or fun... Any tips?

Comment: @user3121023 do you think I should add a separate for loop using `isspace()` to check the new string for spaces?

Comment: Likewise for Vlad's answer if you prefer using index subscripting rather than pointers.

Comment: Thanks everybody! The help is very much appreciated. I'm sitting a basics of C exam on Thursday, and I'm really terrible at programming, but getting there.

Comment: @user3121023 I've tried this but the compiler seems to not like it. This si what you meant? `for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
  check = isalpha(name[i]);
  if ( check == 0 ) {
   for ( j = i ; j < length; j++ ) {
    name[j] = name[j+1];
   }
  i--;
  }
 }`

Comment: @user3121023 It should work? I'm confused as to why it doesn't.. Updated the question so you can see what I've done.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a complicated double-loop for this *at all*. The purpose of the exercise is to maintain independent source-reader and destination-writer, only copying and advancing the latter when the former is qualified by your criteria (i.e. it answers true to `isalpha`).

in other words:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    char name[] = " William B. Gates";
    char *dst = name, *src;

    for (src = name; *src; ++src)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)*src))
            *dst++ = *src;
    }
    *dst = 0; // terminate the string

    printf("result: %s\n", name);
}
```

**Output**

```
result: WilliamBGates
```

I leave translating to lower case during the copy-step as an exercise for you. (from your in-code comment: "makes all alphabetical characters lower case").

Answer (score 6):

This inner loop is wrong

```
    if ( check == 0 ) {
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            name[i] = name[i+1];
        }
```

It copies the string in itself excluding the first character and after that your program does nothing because i is already equal to length.

So the program only removes one non-alpha character from the string.

When you are going to traverse a string sequantially then there is no need to calculate its length. The program can be written simpler or at least you may use the approach that is demonstrated below. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char name[] = " William B. Gates";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );

    size_t j = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )name[i] ) )
        {
            if ( j != i ) name[j] = name[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    name[j] = '\0';

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );

}
```

The program output is

```
" William B. Gates"
"WilliamBGates"
```

Answer (score 1):

The posted code tries to hard.

The following code

- compiles cleanly
- contains useful comments to clarify what is being done
- performs correctly
- uses meaningful variable names

notice the simplicity of the code, and all performed in only one pass through the name[] array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char name[] = " William B. Gates";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );

    size_t src  = 0;
    size_t dest = 0;
    for( ; name[src]; src++)  // will exit loop when string terminator '\0' encountered
    {
        if( isalpha(name[src]) )
        { // then current char is: a...zA...Z
            name[dest] = tolower(name[src]); // force lower case
            dest++; // update where to save next character
        }
    }

    name[dest] = '\0'; // terminate the modified string

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", name );

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a really basic C programmer, could you explain size_t?

Comment: Where in the program does characters which aren't alpha get deleted? I just can't see it.